# Android: Banner ad is not refreshing

Tags: android, admob

The banner ads in my app are not refreshing. I'm using a separate thread to load ad

```
mBottomAdView.setAdListener(new BannerAdListener(BOTTOM));
        Thread adThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .build();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mBottomAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
                }
            });
        }

    };
    adThread.start();
```

It shows up properly 1st time but the ad is not getting refreshed. It remains the same ad unless I restart the app. **I'm using admob for displaying ads**

Answer (score 0):

Adview visibility was set to GONE in xml and I was making it visible on loading of ad. For some reason admob thought my adview is not visible (even when i made it visible programmatically) so it wasn't refreshing ad. I removed visibility parameter from xml and instead used `adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` after `findViewById()` call. Now it's working perfectly.